# How are messages exactly sent in bitcoin p2p protocol

Tags: bitcoin-core, peers

In order to send a `NetMsgType::PING` message to a node `pnode`, we simply invoke the function `pnode->PushMessage(NetMsgType::PING)` in `src/main.cpp`

This translates into following logic in `src/net.h`:

```
void PushMessage(const char* pszCommand)
{
    try
    {
        BeginMessage(pszCommand);
        EndMessage(pszCommand);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        AbortMessage();
        throw;
    }
}
```

If we look carefully, the `BeginMessage` and `EndMessage` are just for acquiring and releasing the lock. Where exactly is the `PING` getting passed to the other node? I think the working is similar for other message types but the overloaded function `PushMessage` may use a Datastream which I guess does the passing to requested node. But I am particularly clueless about cases like `NetMsgType::GETADDR`, `NetMsgType::VERACK` and old version without nonce of `NetMsgType::PING` where there is only the command string `pszCommand` being passed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer myself. Sorry!

The `src/net.cpp` has this logic which explains all:

```
void CNode::BeginMessage(const char* pszCommand) EXCLUSIVE_LOCK_FUNCTION(cs_vSend)
{
    ENTER_CRITICAL_SECTION(cs_vSend);
    assert(ssSend.size() == 0);
    ssSend << CMessageHeader(Params().MessageStart(), pszCommand, 0);
    LogPrint("net", "sending: %s ", SanitizeString(pszCommand));
}
```

Comment: @Jannes - True! But the forum allows me to mark my own post as answer only after two days.